# Add content to Web Part from Modal

Tags: web-part, javascript, visual-web-part, modal-dialog

I'm showing a button, when editing the web part, so the user can click and a modal popups up. This modal should have a couple of option, doesn't matter now, but then I want to save the content so that will be visible on the web part. The modal will be mostly javascript code.

Basically I'm changing the way to edit the web part, just because that side bar doesn't not have enough space for what I want to show.

How can I do this?

Comment: Have you looked into `dialogReturnValueCallback` for the Modal Dialog?

Comment: I used dialogReturnValueCallback before to paste html into the editor content (rich editor). But now I want to paste the html in to the web part which works differently because there's no cursor